# Executing js files in node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a Hello.js file with following contents.

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, "mysite.com");

console.log('Server running at http://mysite.com:1337/');
```

> I go to my command prompt, type in node...

How can i execute this `Hello.js` in my node `console`.

When i type `node Hello.js` , i get .... alone

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/801/hellor.png/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your syntax is wrong, you need:

```
D:\Node > node Hello.js
```

What you're currently doing is starting an interactive session with node, i.e.

```
$ node
> console.log("hello"); # I typed this
hello
>
```